# How to expect and pass in enum as a component property?

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, vuejs3

I created a Vue 3 app using TypeScript. Inside the src folder I created a new enum color.ts

```
enum Color {
    Red,
    Blue
}

export default Color;
```

I created a component ColorDisplay.vue

```
<template>
  <div>
    {{ color }}
  </div>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import { defineComponent } from "vue";
import Color from "../color";

export default defineComponent({
  props: {
      color: {
          type: Color,
          required: true
      }
  }
});
</script>
```

and modified the Home.vue file to

```
<template>
  <div>
    <color-display :color="Color.Red" />
    <color-display :color="Color.Blue" />
  </div>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import { defineComponent } from "vue";
import ColorDisplay from "../components/ColorDisplay.vue";
import Color from "../color";

export default defineComponent({
  components: {
    'color-display': ColorDisplay,
  }
});
</script>
```

Unfortunately several problems come up:

- In Home.vue the imported `Color` is unused although I'm trying to use it in the template
- In ColorDisplay.vue the enum seems to be an invalid prop type

[image]

Would someone mind telling me how to create an enum, expect it as a component property and pass it to components?

Comment: please provide minimum reproducible example in any codesandbox

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Component prop `type` value is restricted to builtin constructors and custom classes. TS enums are not classes but objects with specific types and can't be used as is with `type`.

It likely should be:

```
  color: {
      type: Number as PropType<Color>,
      required: true
  }
```

Comment: and how do I have to use it inside the Home.vue file? To pass it as a prop?

Comment: You need to expose it to the template in setup function, `return { Color }`.

Comment: I also needed to add `import { PropType } from vue;`

Comment: it works, but vue logs a warning:
`[Vue warn]: Invalid prop: type check failed for prop "zoomoption". Expected Object, got String with value "pageFit".`

Comment: @atlmag Means what the error says. It's likely that you did `zoomoption="pageFit"` instead of `:zoomoption="pageFit"`

Comment: @EstusFlask No, I render my vue components as custom elements and it is not another vue element consuming the component in this case.

But it should be added that my prop type is a string enum, they transpile to strings, that's why I didn't expect error messages in runtime

Comment: @EstusFlask the log warning also occurs when the prop default is set to any of the enum values.

Comment: @bvj Please, post the warning

Answer (score 0):

Try annotating the properties with a PropType.
Object as PropType

Here the VueJS 3 Documentation for Annotating Properties: https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/typescript-support.html#annotating-return-types